# Brush Texture, Texture Panel preview blank?

Tags: texture-painting

I am following [Blender Guru's Anvil tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx8Qq7kNKK8) however when I try to create a texture for a brush, the preview for the texture in the properties editor does not display the selected texture (clouds), see the image. Instead, the preview remains grey. The brush does paint with the selected texture.

Why isn't the preview showing correctly?

Thanks

Blender 2.79, Cycles Renderer.

[image: No texture preview - Texture, Properties Editor]

Comment: Check your gpu drivers for an update maybe...

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with this issue for a while. For me it was because I had my render engine set as Workbench, instead of Cycles or Eevee. **Setting the render engine to something other than Workbench** fixed the issue and the texture preview started showing again.

Hope this helps some people.

Comment: I just read this post which is almost 4 years old and it's still the same problem !! And yes, you must not have the 'Workbench' activated, either eevee or cycles!!!
Thanks again.